# Where does tkinter load his fonts from?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I would like to know where does tkinter load his fonts from.

Is it from `/usr/share/fonts` or does it have a specific folder ?

thanks

Comment: It's platform specific. It gets them from the standard font locations for the OS.

Comment: So putting a font family in the standard font location of my OS should enables me to call it from tkinter ?

Comment: Yes, it should. Tkinter uses the system fonts

Comment: Thanks a lot Brian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as Bryan said, tkinter gets the fonts from the standard font locations of the OS. Putting fonts there will permit to tkinter to be able to load them.

Thanks Bryan